# problema con una query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

los molesto porque tengo una query que me esta dando problemas y no encuentro el problemas.
es una tabla de llamadas telefonicas cdrs.

```
select sum(precio) sumaprecio from (
    (select max(preciomaximo) as precio from
        (select ((
         l.preciocompraminuto + l.preciotransito + l.preciotransporte) 
   * l.Duracion_en_segs / 60) * (if((l.preciocompramoneda = 'US$'),57.59,1)) as preciomaximo 
   from llamadas l )as b )
```

la idea es tomar el maximo de la suma de los tres campos multiplicado por la duracion y por el dolar si corresponde o no, eso sumarlo para obtener el importe de los cdrs.

Comment: La funcion `max()` retorna un solo valor, por lo que no tiene sentido hacer un `sum()` despues de eso.  Creo que talvez te falte agrupar los datos de alguna manera.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo primero que realice es reducir las dos subconsultas de `max`a una, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT max(((l.preciocompraminuto + l.preciotransito + l.preciotransporte) * (l.Duracion_en_segs / 60)) * IF(l.preciocompramoneda = 'US$', 57.59, 1)) AS preciomaximo
FROM llamadas l
```

Como ves la operación la realizó dentro del `max` y asi no tienes que usar una subconsulta, ahora bien como te comentan @alanfcm el max solo te devolverá un valor por lo que no estoy seguro por que realizas el `sum`, posiblemente me imagino que luego agruparas con algun campo o algo así de todas formas te dejo el código final con la sumatoria:

```
SELECT
    sum(b.preciomaximo) AS sumaprecio
FROM
(
    SELECT max(((l.preciocompraminuto + l.preciotransito + l.preciotransporte) * (l.Duracion_en_segs / 60)) * IF(l.preciocompramoneda = 'US$', 57.59, 1)) AS preciomaximo
    FROM llamadas l
) b
```

Saludos. ;)